# IIS 404 error on existing text file

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, ffmpeg

I'm running a project on a server which runs IIS 7.5

There's a strange error that I have never seen. The project is written with Codeigniter. I'm converting videos with ffmpeg.exe and writing the results in separate text files for each video. And in the client side it reads the text file for progress.

But the server throws a 404 error for existing txt file. It keeps throwing error until I restart the server. After restarting the server, it can be able to show the text file.

Everything else works perfect. Please help me.

**EDIT:**

.txt files are reachable after amount of time. But it's not certain how much time should pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This isn't a solution to the source of the problem but works for me.

I think, IIS was throwing the 404 error because the file is being processed and locked by ffmpeg. I was getting the file contents by **file_get_contents()** via HTTP address and it returns an empty string or error message. So I decided to use the physical address of the file and to use **read_file()** function with output buffering.

It's now working without any error.